# How Can I Get Admin Id and Use it across the application?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-3

In codeigniter I want to add the product on admin Id which is required in DB Table. when Admin log in his ID must be catch. whenever and where Id is needed it must be available.

here is my **VIEW** in which

```
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/add_product');?>

<!------------------Product Name------------------------>
 <div class="row form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-10"> 

      <label>Product Name: *</label>
  <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'name','class'=>'form-
    control','placeholder'=>'Product name..','value'=> 
   set_value('name')])?> 
      <div>
          <?php echo form_error('name');?>
      </div>
      </div></div>
      <!------------------Product Cat---------------------------->
 <div class="row form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
  <label>Category: *</label> <br>
 <select class="selectpicker" name="pro_cat_id">
<option label="Select Category">Category</option>
<?php
 foreach($product_cat as $cat)
  {?>
  <option value="<?= $cat['pro_cat_id'] ?>"><?= $cat['category'] ?>
 </option>
     <?php }?>
</select>
 <div>

   <!------------------Product Price---------------------------->
 <div class="row form-group">
       <div class="col-md-10">
    <label>Product Price: *</label>
<?php echo form_input(['name'=>'price','class'=>'form-

   control','placeholder'=>'Product Price..','value'=> 
     set_value('price')])?>


   <div>
    <?php echo form_error('price');?>
 </div>
  </div></div>


     <!------------------Product Location---------------------------->
      <div class="row form-group">
       <div class="col-md-10">
      <label>Product Location: *</label>
    <?php //echo form_input(['name'=>'location','class'=>'form-
        control','placeholder'=>'Product Location'])?>

       </div></div>

    </div></div>
        <!-----------End of body---------------->
       </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
     <input name="" type="submit" value="ADD" class="btn btn-success">

     </div>

         <?php echo form_close();?>
     </div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my **Controller**

```
            function add_product(){  
       $data['product_size'] = $this->show->show_product_size();
      $data['product_cat']= $this->show->show_product_category();
      $data['product_color'] = $this->show->show_product_color();
   $data['pr']= $this->show->show_provider();

    $post= $this->input->post();
  $ =this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<p class='text-danger'>","
  </p>");
if($this->form_validation->run('add_product')){
if($this->add->add_product($post)==TRUE){

     $this->db->close();
     $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Product has been added 
       successfully');
    return redirect('admins/pages/add_product_page');
     //$this->load->admin_template('admin/add_product',$data);

}
}
else
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('failled','Sorry, fail to add product');
    //return redirect('admins/pages/add_product_page');
    $upload_error= $this->upload->display_errors();

     $this->load->admin_template('admin/add_product',$data);
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query, preferably in your controller:

```
$this->session->userdata('id');
```

Comment: then how I can store that Id( id in table) to this session id.....does it take it in automatic?